# Read file with some fiddler like jsBin/jsFiddle/codePen

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've the following odata file and I want to read it and to get the document with some code playground tool,is it possible ?

http://services.odata.org/V4/(S(1j4xrnlnwnnmvagwtgl2envc))/TripPinServiceRW/$metadata

I tried like following and its not working
http://jsfiddle.net/y6XgY/490/

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://services.odata.org/V4/(S(1j4xrnlnwnnmvagwtgl2envc))/TripPinServiceRW/$metadata',
    success: function(data) {
        log('in success callback');
        log('received data: ' + data);
        //enable the button
        $('#button').attr('disabled', false);
    }
});

console.log(data)
```

Comment: do an ajax call, whats the problem here?

Comment: I've tried without success...

Comment: what is response of ajax call..?

Comment: @shopiaT please post what you have tried so far.

Comment: @Banana-http://jsfiddle.net/y6XgY/490/

Comment: @shopiaT Please check the fiddle i created i hope that will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a fiddle for you it's working fine

```
<div id="container">

</div>

$.ajax({
    url: 'http://services.odata.org/V4/(S(1j4xrnlnwnnmvagwtgl2envc))/TripPinServiceRW/$metadata',
    success: function(data) {
        console.log('in success callback');
        $("#container").text(new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(data));
    }
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sez9ra04/)